# Tracking linear movement on mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, accelerometer, motion-detection

I know this question has already been asked, but all of the posts I can find are at least 2 years old, has everybody given up?

I would like to use iOS/Android devices to measure small distances (around 3D objects), is it possible to do it with an error of under 1cm?

I know double integration of acceleration values (cleaned up with sensor fusion) is not ideal, but is there any other approach really?

Thanks

Comment: You have hardware limit (gyro white noise). See the linked question for example to see what you can do instead.

Comment: Yep, I read that, but was wondering if anyone had a different approach.

Comment: There is no other approach: **We have reached the hardware limit.** That's all there is to it. The other approaches all involve some source of external reference for the position or some domain specific assumption or better hardware (ring laser gyro for example). Or try to change the requirements in such a way that you can use orientation in your application instead of position. You can do a lot of cool stuff with just orientation.

Comment: OK, I will see to that, thanks.